# Response Header in php

Tags: php, response

I want to know that how to send a response using header in php . When an application or an User hit my URL then i have to send a response header with response 1 for failure and 0 for success, and if the response is success (0) then i have to send two values in response header.

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong, but thats http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php the only way to modify your response header.

Comment: I suggest you use the proper status code instead of "1 for failure and 0 for success".  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6164319/362536

Answer (score 1):

The [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function will allow you to set a header.

```
header("foo", 1);
```

… but it sounds like you are reinventing [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: Also, if you must invent your own headers, use `X-Foo`... prefix your own custom headers with `X-`.