# How to configure Parsley remote validator to handle my API response

Tags: parsley.js

I have tried all the possible approaches found, but I am struggled to get the default remote validator working.

I'm just trying to achieve to check if the mail for a registration page of a user is duplicated. Thus, I declare the input as follows:

```
<input type="email" name="email" required
                                   placeholder="Dirección de correo"
                                   data-parsley-trim-value="true"
                                   data-parsley-trigger="change"
                                   data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp" }'
                                   data-parsley-remote="checkmail.php"
                                   data-parsley-remote-message="Mail duplicated"
                                   class="form-control">
```

The checkmail.php code is:

```
require_once("../functions/mysqli_connect.php");
if (empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors[] = 'No llega el parametro de mail';
}else {
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

$q = ("select * from register where email ='" . $email . "'");
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

if ($r) {
    if (($r->num_rows) > 0) {
        echo json_encode(404);

    } else {
        echo json_encode(200);
    }
}
```

}

I've tried multiple combinations for echo response, I've read all the messages on stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution because I've always get the message :
**This value seems to be invalid.**

As I read on another's user question I've tried:

```
data-parsley-remote-message="Mail duplicated"
```

but with no luck either.

The PHP code works as expected, so no errors there, but Parsley always treats the json_encode responses as it is was an error.

Any help would be vey appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsley remote validator looks for **HTTP response code** not for the body content itself. In your example you're returning json data with probably always HTTP 200 status code.

Maybe look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php or here [Set Response Status Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163970/set-response-status-code) to see how you could change the response status code.

Best

Comment: Hi guillaumepotier, first of all, thanks for your incredible development and answering questions like mine.

In my case I'm returning response codes, because I saw your answer in another thread saying that, but I really don't know what my php server code need to answer. I tried many many things.

May be the right questions are: 
- What the server code need to answer in order to indicate to parsley the OK and KO conditions? HTTP Responses, php key-value pairs...?
- In which format (json, plain text,...) need to be answered?

Again, thank you very much for your interest and software.

Esteve.

Comment: Parsley 2.0 currently only look for HTTP Response status: 200 => OK everything else => NOK. If you're more comfortable with javascript than PHP, you can in parsley remote define your custom validator to look for something else, for example the json response code, like shown here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#extras Hope that helps

Comment: Thank very much, it worked, when I changed echo json_encode(200) for echo http_response_code(200) and echo json_encode(404) for echo http_response_code(404).

All the best and again thank you for your support